# Android: DialogFragment show throws illegalstateexception after web service call

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

In my app I am showing a dialog fragment after I get response from web service. I am calling this service from `onCreate`. In between if app goes to background, it crashes with exception

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1493)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1511)
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:638)
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:617)
   at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:139)
   at com.activity.MainActivity.showAcceptancePopup(MainActivity.java:1655)
   at com.activity.MainActivity.access$1000(MainActivity.java:164)
   at com.activity.MainActivity$28.onResponse(MainActivity.java:1568)
   at com.activity.MainActivity$28.onResponse(MainActivity.java:1547)
   at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:65)
   at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

I have gone through [this blog post](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html). Still having doubt, from where should I call `dialogFragment.show()` as it depends on the data provided by the server.

Or else should I move the API call from `onCreate` to `onResumeFragment`?

Answer (score 1):

The solution here is to using `commitAllowingStateLoss();` instead of `commit()` for your fragment transaction, as according by the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commitAllowingStateLoss())

> Like commit() but allows the commit to be executed after an activity's
>   state is saved

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can do it but I don't want state loss to be happened

Comment: I see, where are you doing your fragment transaction ?

Comment: I am making web service call from onCreate and in response I am showing the dialog. For api calls, I am using volley

Comment: According to the blog post , you can try to call the web service in `onPostResume()`.